# making a TreeView of our own file explorer

Tags: c#, wpf, file, xaml, treeview

I'm trying to get a file explorer on c# and I have found nothing about this. Is c# provide a file explorer already ready to work?

If not, is TreeView a good idea to create mine? Have you got some link to perform this?

Thanks in advance for these informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# Doesn't provide file explorer tree as it is, but if you want to create a dialog for selecting the folder you can use [FolderBrowserDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx)(full dialog for folder selection)

However if you want to create one, yes, It is easy to do it with WPF TreeView.
As a hint
  Take TreeView, write HiearchyDataProvider which provides files and folders and templates for each node to display icons and so on

P.S.
  Simple google search shows a lot of ready-[samples](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21248/A-Simple-WPF-Explorer-Tree)

Comment: In addition to the `FolderBrowserDialog`, which is to browse for folders, the [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can be used for selecting one or multiple files instead of folders.

Comment: I'll see the FolderBrowserDialog, thanks, I have, I think, everything I ned to do this.